# How to write mouse enter event for nested each elements in meteor?

Tags: jquery, html, meteor

I want to display the content inside class="ui fluid popup left transition hidden" using popup when mouse enter.
which is fetch from db based on particular project and release and job.

My problem is mouse enter and exit event works only for one box. it is because element inside nested each, id assign to first box not for all. how to solve this [wandisco and cloudera are platform and sp1, sp2 are releases, CEI,CQI are projects, and tabs with green,red yellow are jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0GW3.png)

status.html

```
  <div class="example tabClick">
    <div class="ui two item inverted small menu" style="margin:0 0.5%">
        <a class="item active sbtn1" data-tab="wan"><h4>Wandisco</h4></a>
        <a class="item sbtn2" data-tab="second"><h4>Cloudera</h4></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui small tab active" data-tab="wan" id="Outer">
        <div class="ui top attached blue tiny tabular menu">
            {{#each listRelease}}
                <a class="item" data-tab="wan/{{this.release}}"><h4>{{this.release}}</h4></a>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
        {{#each listRelease}}  
            <div class="ui bottom attached tab menu" data-tab="wan/{{this.release}}" id="rel">
                <div class="ui menu grids" style="margin-top:0;">
                    {{#each listProjName this.release}}
                        <div class=" column equal width aligned padded center aligned">
                            <div class="ui vertical allifluid  menu"><center><p><h4>{{this.project}}</h4></p></center>
                                {{#each listjobName this.release this.project}}
                                    <div class="ui small menu" style="background-color:{{getStatusColor buildStatus}}; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 3px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 8px;" id="jbox">
                                        <p id="viewJob"><h5>{{job}}</h5></p>
                                        <div class="ui fluid popup left transition hidden">
                                            <div class="ui column relaxed grid">
                                                <a class="item">Last Build: {{lastBuild}}</a>
                                                <a class="item">Last Successful Build: {{lastSuccess}}</a>
                                                <a class="item">Duration: {{lastDuration}}</a>
                                                <a class="item">Robo Results: {{robotResult}}</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                {{/each}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {{/each}}
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</div>
```

my mouse enter and leave events are below.
status.js

```
Template.status.events({
'mouseenter #jbox'(event, instance ) {
    console.log("mouse enter"); 
          $(".popup").show();

  },
  'mouseleave #jbox'(event, instance) {
  console.log("mouse exit");
  $(".popup").hide();
  },

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jankapunkt is on the right track, but you'll want to target the `.popup` which is a child of the element under the mouse:

```
Template.status.events({
  'mouseenter .jbox'(event, instance ) {
    console.log("mouse enter"); 
    $(event.currentTarget).children('.popup').show();
  },
  'mouseleave .jbox'(event, instance) {
    console.log("mouse exit");
    $(event.currentTarget).children('.popup').hide();
  },
});
```

Comment: No it is not working in my case. its entering inside event when i hover but not showing the popup content.

Comment: Ya its working but popup is showing back side of project box. so it cant be seen.

Comment: give it position absolute and positive z-index in css

Comment: Thank you so much its working.. and how to display pop up right side of each job.

Answer (score 1):

You define `jbox` via id, which is intened for elements, that occur **once**. However, inside your `#each` this element will occur many times, so an id for dereferencing is not a good solution here.

You then better use a `class` attribute:

```js
<div class="jbox ui small menu" style="background-color:{{getStatusColor buildStatus}}; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 3px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 8px;">
```

You also need to change the event selector signature then from using `#` (dereferencing ids) to `.` (dereferencing classes).

```js
Template.status.events({
  'mouseenter .jbox'(event, instance ) {
    console.log("mouse enter"); 
    $(".popup").show();
  },
  'mouseleave .jbox'(event, instance) {
    console.log("mouse exit");
    $(".popup").hide();
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. it is entering into mouseenter mouseleave event now but  $(".popup").show(); is not working. Is there any mistake in selector?

Comment: And same problem to add drag and drop for project box. In onrender i added dragula([document.querySelector('.allifluid.menu')]); and drag and drop is not working.